# A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Tags: c#

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Do you want to delete?", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            executeQueryDB("DELETE FROM student_biodata WHERE std_matric_no='" + txtmatric.Text + "'", "Record Deleted successfully!");
            GetData();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        executeQueryDB("UPDATE student_biodata SET std_lastname=" + txtlastname.Text + " std_firstname=" + txtfirstname.Text + "std_phone_no=" + txtphoneno.Text + " std_gender=" + txtgender.Text + " std_previousQND=" + txtpreviousqnd.Text + " std_DOB= " + txtdob.Text + " std_address=" + txtaddress .Text + " std_programme=" + txtprogramme .Text + " std_session=" + txtsession .Text + "std_faculty=" + txtfaculty .Text + " std_department=" + txtdepartment .Text + " std_email=" + txtemail .Text + "  std_top='" + txttop .Text + "'  WHERE std_matric_no=' + txtmatric .Text +' ","Student Data Update successfully!");
        GetData();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        executeQueryDB ("INSERT INTO student_biodata (std_matric_no, std_lastname, std_firstname, std_phone_no, std_gender, std_previous_QND, std_DOB, std_address, std_programme, std_session, std_faculty, std_department, std_email, std_top) VALUES("+ txtmatric.Text + "," + txtlastname.Text + "," + txtfirstname.Text + "," + txtphoneno.Text+ "," + txtgender.Text + ",'" + txtpreviousqnd.Text + "'," + txtdob.Text + "," + txtaddress.Text + "," + txtprogramme.Text + "," + txtsession.Text + "," + txtfaculty.Text + "," + txtdepartment.Text + "," + txtemail.Text + "," + txttop.Text +") ","Student Data Added Successfully!");
    GetData();
    }
    private void GetData()
    {
        OpenConnection ();
       sql ="SELECT * FROM student_biodata";
        cmd =new MySqlCommand (sql,cn);
        da .SelectCommand =cmd ;
        tb =new DataTable ();
        da.Fill (tb);
        dataGridView1 .DataSource =tb.DefaultView ;
        CloseConnection ();
    }
```

I'm getting the following exception in `button2_Click`

> A first chance exception of type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Comment: please, i need your help

Comment: Look at the exception details - including any inner exceptions - to see what the actual problem is

Comment: Youve listed 3 queries does it fail on all of them? 1 of them? you havent shown what happens in executeQueryDB .. your work is very open to sql injection.. and then as other have said, you need to look at the exception and read what its complaining of

Comment: it complained of   Additional information: Unknown column 'std_previousQND' in 'field list'

Comment: you have very inconsistent use of single quotes around your query values. Use command parameters instead.

Comment: you spell that column differently between the insert and update commands.

Comment: i made sure that i was consistent using the " and i also corrected the mistake of misspelled std_previousQND..now it is saying this when i try to insert
Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,,,,,,,,,)' at line 1

Comment: I'm not surprised, it is a very error prone way to do it. See un-lucky's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the approach, you are using plain text queries which is the worst method as it opens a wide door for `SQL Injection attacks`. You can avoid them by using parametrized queries. Another thing is the syntax error that you made while building the `Update` query. you missed the comma in between column names.

You have to form the parametrized Update query like this(let `command` be the command):

```
command.Text = "UPDATE student_biodata SET std_lastname= @lname, std_firstname= @fname  WHERE std_matric_no=@no";
// Include column name and values as per your needs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLastName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname  ", txtFirstName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", matricNo);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i will try this one